# extending captions for A3 pages

Tags: captions, margins, paper-size

Im writing my Thesis in A4 format and sometimes I need to use A3 pages for bigger images. 
I managed to create a single A3 page within the A4 document and I extended the header up to the right margin. However, the text justification for the caption is still set up as an A4 document. 
Does anyone know how to adjust the caption to the size of the image (in an A3 image)? this is the last bit I need to correct before submitting =)

Here you have what I'm doing...(--EDITED-- to have a complete document. I'm working with a preamble so I copied all the packages I'm using in order to have the setting up as I have...)

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}


\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{18}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{lscape}



\usepackage[portuges,brazilian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{textcomp}



\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  %gives \textsubscript
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{sidecap}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}


\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{indentfirst}


\usepackage{array}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%Sets margins...
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=4cm, left=4cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

%Customises figure captions...
\usepackage[small,justification=justified,format=plain,labelsep=space,indention=0cm,margin={0cm,0cm},labelfont={rm,bf},up,textfont={rm,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

%customises header...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
 \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textrm{\normalsize{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textrm{\normalsize{{{\leftmark}}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textrm{\large{{{\rightmark}}}}}






\begin{document}

\clearpage{
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth
\fancyheadoffset[R]{20cm} 

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.3\textwidth]{LATEX/C8/IMAGES/SCENARIOB}
    \caption[Results of Burial scenario B  - maturity window]{ResultsB - Burial scenario B contemplating transient heat flow (B-transient) and rifting heat flow (B-rifting). B-transient-I is contemplating a geothermal gradient of 30$^\circ$C/km for the overburden calculation; B-transient-II is contemplating a geothermal gradient of 20$^\circ$C/km for the overburden calculation; B-transient-III is contemplating a geothermal gradient of 15$^\circ$C/km for the overburden calculation. B-rifting is contemplating a $\beta$=1.3. }
    \label{SCENARIO B}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
}

\pdfpagewidth=1\pdfpagewidth



\end{document}
```

Here how it looks...( in this particular case, the image is not covering the whole page, but that is just because of the size of the image, it's not an error):

[image: A3 image, caption justified for an A4 page]

Comment: Welcome at [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please make it a fully compilable example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`? It would help the solvers a lot to start experimenting with your example!

Comment: You can probably add simply `\hsize=2\linewidth` to the figure. Or if you use the caption package `\captionsetup{width=2\linewidth}`. But imho such long text lines are awful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replies... -Malipivo, I've just added the complete document with the packages so you can have a look. You will need to change the image of the figure so it can work properly. -Ulrike, I tried with the captionsetup... but nothing happens... Hope you can give me some advise. Thanks in advance...